# How to configure routes for auth user and unauth user in expo router?

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

I'm using expo SDK 49 and expo router v2. I have a route structure like this:

```
(main)
 | dashboard.tsx
 | profile.tsx
 | order.tsx
 | wishlist.tsx
 | history.tsx
(home)
 | _layout.tsx
 | index.tsx
 | products.tsx
 | offers.tsx
login.tsx
_layout.tsx
```

The _layout.tsx at root is like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Tabs } from 'react-router';

export default function RootLayout(){
 return (
<Tabs>
  <Tabs.Screen name="(home)" />
  <Tabs.Screen name="login" />
  <Tabs.Screen name="(main)/dashboard" />
  <Tabs.Screen name="(main)/profile" />
  <Tabs.Screen name="(main)/order" />
  <Tabs.Screen name="(main)/wishlist" />
  <Tabs.Screen name="(main)/history" />
</Tabs>
)}
```

I'm writing this code for both web and native using expo.

My requirement is to make the user go to (home)/index if they just hit my website url like `https://www.example.com`.

This works with the existing implementation. The code in `(home)/_layout.tsx` is applied successfully to all the home screens. I can go to login route from home screens as well. Then the user can login and go to the screens in main successfully.

I have new requirement that I want all of the screens in (main) to have a different header and footer. So basically I want to create a _layout.tsx in (main) and add a header/footer, then add some custom api code.

While I tried to do it, I moved the screens in _layout.tsx to (main)/_layout.tsx with Tabs, like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Tabs } from 'react-router';

export default function MainLayout(){
 return (
<Tabs>
  <Tabs.Screen name="dashboard" /> //Tried giving (main)/ prefix to all the routes as well
  <Tabs.Screen name="profile" />
  <Tabs.Screen name="order" />
  <Tabs.Screen name="wishlist" />
  <Tabs.Screen name="history" />
</Tabs>
)}
```

and now the root _layout.tsx is like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Tabs } from 'react-router';

export default function RootLayout(){
 return (
<Tabs>
  <Tabs.Screen name="(home)" />
  <Tabs.Screen name="login" />
  <Tabs.Screen name="(main)" />
</Tabs>
)}
```

Now when the user is already authenticated and visiting `https://www.example.com/dashboard`, it gives me error that 'dashboard' doesn't exist as a route, which is true. I only gave (main) in tabs.

I'm confused in how to apply a layout to (main) screens and also move authenticated users directly to dashboard. Please keep in mind that I can't create a index.tsx in (main) folder because (home)/index.tsx is already there and an url without any routes such as `https://www.example.com` should take me to home index.

My required structure should look something like this:

```
(main)
 | _layout.tsx
 | dashboard.tsx
 | profile.tsx
 | order.tsx
 | wishlist.tsx
 | history.tsx
(home)
 | _layout.tsx
 | index.tsx
 | products.tsx
 | offers.tsx
login.tsx
_layout.tsx
```

Basically `https://www.example.com/dashboard` should take user to dashboard if they are authenticated.

Please help. Thank you.